# Erro com argumentos Foreach

Tags: php, foreach

Criei uma estrutura com alguns loops contudo o php tá me retornando que os argumentos do foreach são inválidos... Eu não tenho certeza se essa estrutura é correta, então gostaria que alguém me informasse se isso é ou não correto:

```
for($x=1; x<=$n_cartelas_registradas; $x++) {
$contador[$x] = 0;
foreach($cartela[$x] as $n_cartela=>$numero){ //linha retornando erro
  for($a=0; $a<=$n_sort; $a++){
    if($numero == $sorteados_array[$a]){
     $contador[$x]++; 
       }
    }
  }
}
```

Todas as variáveis usadas têm valores.
O array cartela tem a seguinte estrutura: `$cartela[1] = array (n, q, e, r, t);` e esses valores não são arrays. Ou seja, é bidimensional. Já o `$sorteados_array` é da seguinte forma: `$sorteados_array[0] = x;` ou seja; é um array unidimensional.

Então, os argumentos do foreach podem ser escritos dessa forma? 
Se sim, onde pode estar o erro? Se não, como posso obter o resultado esperado de forma correta?
Obrigado.

Comment: N, q, e, r, t **não são** arrays mas é bidimensional? Não está nada claro.. Favor postar um var_dump de $cartela

Comment: Pelo seu código estimo que esteja esquecendo de inicializar algum dos arrays dentro da variavel $cartela;
Poderia nos fornecer o código completo?

Comment: Realmente precisaríamos ver o que tem na `$cartela`. Mas estrahei o seu loop de `1` até `$n_cartelas_registradas`. Não deveria ser de `0` a `$n_cartelas_registradas - 1`?

Comment: Errei na hora de escrever... Elas são arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faltou o cifrão na variável `$x` da condição.

```
for($x=1; x <= $n_cartelas_registradas; $x++)
----------^
```

Troque por:

```
for($x=1; $x <= $n_cartelas_registradas; $x++) {
```